# Error 404 occurs when switching to the category page for the created taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

I created taxonomy and type post.

```
// My post type
add_action('init', 'register_post_types_carshowroom');
function register_post_types_carshowroom() {
    register_post_type('carshowroom', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name'               => 'Автосалоны',
            'singular_name'      => 'Автосалон',
            'add_new'            => 'Добавить автосалон',
            'add_new_item'       => 'Добавление автосалона',
            'edit_item'          => 'Редактирование автосалон',
            'new_item'           => 'Новый автосалон',
            'view_item'          => 'Смотреть автосалон',
            'search_items'       => 'Искать автосалон',
            'not_found'          => 'Не найдено',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'Не найдено в корзине',
            'parent_item_colon'  => '',
            'menu_name'          => 'Автосалоны',
        ),
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'menu_icon'           => true,
        'supports'            => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments'),
        'taxonomies'          => array('carshowroom_cat'),
    ));
}

// My taxonomy
add_action('init', 'add_taxonomy_carshowroom', 0);
function add_taxonomy_carshowroom() {   
    register_taxonomy(
        'carshowroom_cat',
        'carshowroom',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Категории',
                'singular_name' => 'Категория',
                'search_items' =>  'Найти категорию',
                'popular_items' => 'Популярные категории',
                'all_items' => 'Все категории',
                'parent_item' => null,
                'parent_item_colon' => null,
                'edit_item' => 'Редактировать категорию', 
                'update_item' => 'Обновить категорию',
                'add_new_item' => 'Добавить новую категорию',
                'new_item_name' => 'Название новой категории',
                'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Разделяйте категории запятыми',
                'add_or_remove_items' => 'Добавить или удалить категорию',
                'choose_from_most_used' => 'Выбрать из наиболее часто используемых категорий',
                'menu_name' => 'Категории'
            ),
            'hierarchical'          => true,
            'public'                => true, 
            'publicly_queryable'    => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
            'show_ui'               => true,
            'show_tagcloud'         => true,
            'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
            'query_var'             => true,
            'rewrite'               => array(
                'slug'         => 'carshowroom_cat',
                'hierarchical' => true

            ),
        )
    );
}
```

Next, I re-saved the settings for permanent links:
/%category%/%postname%/
I created post for my post stype and category fo my taxonomy. I assigned this category to this post. I created template "taxonomy-carshowroom_cat.php".

Error 404 occurs when switching to the category page for the created taxonomy:
https://avtospletnik.com/carshowroom_cat/salon-moscow/

Could you explain to me what I'm doing wrong?